# Using gsub from all values in dataframe with strings

Tags: r, replace, gsub

If I have a dataframe was values such as:

```
df<- c("One", "Two Three", "Four", "Five")
df<-data.frame(df)

df
"One"
"Two Three"
"Four"
"Five"
```

And I have another dataframe such as:

```
df2<-c("the park was number one", "I think the park was number two three", "Nah one and two is ok", "tell me about four and five")
df2<-data.frame(df2)

df2
the park was number one
I think the park was number two three
Nah one and two is ok
tell me about four and five
```

If one of the values found in df are found in any of the strings of df2[,1], how do I replace it with a word like "it".

I want to replace my final df2 with this:

```
df3
the park was number it
I think the park was number it
Nah it and two is ok
tell me about it and it
```

I know it probably has to do with something like:

```
gsub(df,"it", df2)
```

But I don't think that is right.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have been around enough to know that you need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) rather than copy/pasting your data.

Comment: Sorry just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
sapply(df$df,function(w) df2$df2 <<- gsub(paste0(w,"|",tolower(w)),"it",df2$df2))

df2 
                             df2
1         the park was number it
2 I think the park was number it
3           Nah it and two is ok
4        tell me about it and it
```

The `<<-` operator makes sure that the version of `df2` in the global environment is changed by the function.  The `paste0(w,"|",tolower(w))` allows for differences of capitalisation, as in your example.

Note that you should add `stringAsFactors=FALSE` to your dataframe definitions in the question.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, can you modify your answer for dataframes? I just made the edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks! And then do I just convert it back to a dataframe and filter out one of the columns?

Comment: Done! It only affects `df` because of the way that `lapply` works, `df2` should work as it was before.

Comment: Sorry - I've changed `df2` as well - that way it will come out as a dataframe.